# What is the song of ice and fire?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In "A Clash of Kings", while Daenerys is in the House of the Undying, one of the visions is:

> Beyond loomed a cavernous stone hall, the largest she had ever seen. [...] Upon a towering barbed throne sat an old man in rich robes, an old man with dark eyes and  long silver-grey hair. [...]
>
> Viserys, was her first thought the next time she paused, but a second glance told her otherwise. [...] "Aegon", he said to a woman nursing a newborn babe in a great wooden bed. "What a better name for a king?"
>
> "Will you make a song for him?" the woman asked.
>
> "He has a song," the
> man replied. "He is the prince that was promised, **and his is the song
> of ice and fire**".
>
> <sub>A Clash of Kings, Chapter 48, Daenerys IV.</sub>

My question is this: What is the song of ice and fire? And why is it Aegon's ?

Comment: Not Aegon the Conqueror, the boy is Rhaegar's son, Aegon.

Comment: Damn it! I came here to +1, but i'd already done it a while ago!

Comment: It sounds to me like he will be important between the fight between light and dark and the song of ice and fire would be the saga of that battle afterwards. That's what I took from it anyway and the constant allusions by Melisandre that there is someone from the House Targaryen lineage who is Azor Ahai reborn- it's not Stannis and Daenerys seems a bit preoccupied :P

Comment: Some people speculate that Aegon is the son of Rhaegar and Lyanna. A Targaryen and a Stark. Fire and Ice.

Comment: @IvoBeckers Except that a more probable Candidate for child of Rhaegar and Lyanna is Jon rather than Young Griff.

Comment: @Aegon I agree. At the time that I wrote that comment I actually hadn't finished the books yet, and of course R+L=J wasn't revealed yet.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The answer below has been shamelessly ripped off from the [A Song of Ice and Fire wikia](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/The_song_of_ice_and_fire).

---

The song of ice and fire is a subject of a prophecy and is eponymous for the "A Song of Ice and Fire" series of book. The song of ice and fire is said to be [the prince that was promised](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/The_prince_that_was_promised)'s but **the content of the actual song remains unknown**.

At the House of the Undying, Daenerys Targaryen sees a man (Rhaegar Targaryen) and overhears him talking to a woman (Elia Martell) nursing a baby; "Aegon… What better name for a king… He is the prince that was promised, and **his is the song of ice and fire**"

However, neither Daenerys nor Ser Jorah Mormont know what the song of ice and fire means. It is implied that there is a connection between the song, the promise, and Daenerys herself.

The phrase "ice and fire" is also mentioned in the Reeds' oath of loyalty to Bran Stark. The phrase "ice and fire" appears two more times in the books as an example of opposites however, the song and the promise are never mentioned again, and the song itself remains a mystery.

[George R. R. Martin](http://www.adriasnews.com/2012/10/george-r-r-martin-interview.html) has said that he was influenced by Robert Frost’s poem [Fire and Ice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_and_Ice_%28poem%29)

> **Interviewer : Why your saga is called A Song of Ice and Fire, because of the Wall and the dragons or is something more beyond that?**
>
> **GRRM :** Oh! That’s the obvious thing but yes, there’s more. People say I was influenced by Robert Frost’s poem, and of course I was, I mean... Fire is love, fire is passion, fire is sexual ardor and all of these things. Ice is betrayal, ice is revenge, ice is… you know, that kind of cold inhumanity and all that stuff is being played out in the books.

Comment: Even though this question specifically asks about the books, it might make sense to mention the latest development from the show - since this changes the identity of some characters mentioned in this answer.