# What is the in-universe title of Yandel's ‘A World of Ice and Fire’?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

The title has it all. The book written by Elio Garcia Jr & Linda Antonsson was released in 2014 under the title *A World of Ice and Fire! The Untold History of Westeros and the Game of Thrones.* However, in-universe this is supposed to be the work of a Maester by the name of Yandel, and was supposed to be a gift for King Robert Baratheon, then Jeoffrey, then Tommen.

Throughout the book, many other works of Maesters were evoked, and each and every one has a name, a title given by the author — for instance, Maester Childer's *Winter's Kings or the Legends and Lineages of the Starks of Winterfel*, or Maester Kerth's *Songs the Drowned Men Sing*.

Has Yandel chosen a title for his work, and if so, what is it?

Comment: Good question. Judging by the answer to ["What is the song of ice and fire?"](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51208/what-is-the-song-of-ice-and-fire), it sounds like "ice and fire" is a moderately common idiom for opposites and doesn't have any other particularly widely-known significance, so it could actually be "A world of ice and fire", which would in-world be taken to mean "A world of contrasts and opposites", and wouldn't be particularly Targaryan (Dany didn't recognise the expression when she heard probably-Rhaegar say it in her dream)

Comment: "*There and Back Again: A Hobbit's Tale by Bilbo Baggins*"

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**As the co-author of this book**, I can confirm that the in-world title is indeed 'The World of Ice and Fire'.

Comment: I have [confirmed](https://twitter.com/westerosorg/status/691581218136129536) that this is the real [Elio (aka Ran)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Song_of_Ice_and_Fire_fandom) who is one of the co-authors of *The World of Ice and Fire*. So he knows because he wrote the damn thing!